# C# Custom Memory Stream

Tags: c#, memory, memorystream, libvlc, libvlcsharp

I would like to create a small media player that uses the LibVLCSharp API. To avoid possible stutters, I want to partially load the videos into memory, and pass a MemoryStream to the API. Passing the stream to the VLC API works without problems.

Since my video files can be over 20 GB in size, I want to load them only partially into memory.

For example: I have a 1h video which is ~20GB in size.
At the beginning I would like to load the first 5min(~2GB) into memory.
When the first minute of the video has been played, the data of this first minute should be deleted and the 6th minute should be loaded into RAM.

Can someone provide me with a code example on how to implement something like this?

Answer (score 0):

VLC already does its own buffering, is there a reason you don't pass a FileStream directly?

Do you need to seek into the video? If not, I'd try to use PipeReader/PipeWriter as a MediaInput implementation. I don't think we have code for that, but we would welcome a sample.

If you need to seek into the video, then use a FileStream, or, if not possible, implement your own Stream subclass to access to your file. VLC will do the buffering.

You don't give much info about the "stutterings" so we can't really help about that. Does that happen when you're trying to read your data in a MemoryStream?

Comment: Can I achieve, that vlc buffers the video before i call the play-function?

Comment: Maybe try to call `Parse()` to make it preload the stream. I'm not sure if that would be enough.